# Using Conditions in XPath Query

Tags: java, logging, xpath, pmd

I'm trying to write a PMD rule for my repo where I need all logger classes to be only of type log4j.
Eg:

Code:

```
import some;
class Foo{
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class.getName());
    }
}
```

My XPath Query for PMD rule:

```
(//ImportDeclaration //Name[@Image!='org.apache.log4j.Logger'] ) 
|
( //ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration //FieldDeclaration //Type //ReferenceType //ClassOrInterfaceType[@Image='Logger'])
```

I'm testing here if the Logger class is used in code & it is not of type log4j, then it's a violation.

Comment: This xpath query seems to have some error. I want to check if Logger object is created in a class, then there should be an import of apache log4j. But I'm unable to put and operator or if..else condition for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since there can be star imports, same package accesses and simple and fully qualified names, I'd suggest you use [typeresolution](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.5/customizing/howtowritearule.html#I_need_some_kind_of_Type_Resolution_for_my_rule).

```
//ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration//FieldDeclaration//Type//ReferenceType//ClassOrInterfaceType[ends-with(@Image, 'Logger') and not(typeof(@Image, 'org.apache.log4j.Logger', 'Logger'))]
```

The final rule would be stated as:

```
<rule name="All Loggers must be Log4J Loggers"
      message="All Loggers must be Log4J Loggers"
      class="net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule"
      language="java"
      typeResolution="true">
    <description>
        All Loggers must be Log4J Loggers
    </description>
    <priority>3</priority>
    <properties>
        <property name="xpath">
            <value>
    //ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration//FieldDeclaration//Type//ReferenceType//ClassOrInterfaceType[ends-with(@Image, 'Logger') and not(typeof(@Image, 'org.apache.log4j.Logger', 'Logger'))]
            </value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

Notice the `typeResolution="true"` attribute on the `rule` node. Also make sure to populate the auxclasspath for type resolution properly. Gradle does it automatically, on Maven you have to [enable it through configuration](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html#typeResolution), with Ant you need to manually pass the `auxclasspath`.

One final note, this rule as is will only look for fields, unused imports / star imports for other loggers will go undetected, and even if they could be added, I'd simply go with [the existing rule](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.5/pmd-java/rules/java/imports.html#UnusedImports) to deal with unused imports.